# Action link button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am moving over from VB to C# and am having problems trying to work out an equivalent in C# for the following razor code (which shows an action link as a button)?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Send Message", "SendCustomerMessage", "SendMessage", 
             New With {.id = currentItem.CustomerId}, New With {.class = "btn"})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VB but it should work when you create anonymous objects like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Send Message", "SendCustomerMessage", "SendMessage", 
                     new {id = currentItem.CustomerId}, new  { @class = "btn"})
```

We need `@` before `class` property because `class` is a reserverd word in C#. You may want to read more about [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

### **Override**

[image]

### **Razor**

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "Action", "Controller", 
                   new { @id = currentItem.CustomerId }, new { @class = "abc" })
```